# Sencha Touch 2 dependency errors while packing

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to pack my new app for iOS, but getting an error when resolving application dependencies.

```
$ sencha app build native
[INFO] Deploying your application to /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/appcode/build/package
[INFO] Copied sdk/sencha-touch.js
[INFO] Copied app.js
[INFO] Copied resources/css/app.css
[INFO] Copied resources/images
[INFO] Resolving your application dependencies...
[ERROR]
```

It doesn't specify WHERE the error occurs (that would've been nice!). What can I do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found out it was a bug in Sencha's packager on OSX Lion. Works perfectly in Snow Leopard and Windows 7.

Comment: Do you have additional information? Is there a thread with more details?

Answer (score 0):

Have you made the change `"platform":"iOS",` in the Package.json file ?